# Get (1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4) from (1, 2, 3, 4) in R

Tags: r, rep

I have vector

```
z1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

and want to get from it another vector

```
z2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4,
           2, 3, 4,
              3, 4,
                 4)
```

I've tried different variants of rep() function, but get only this

```
z3 <- rep(z1, times=seq(length(z1), 1))

z3 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1,
           2, 2, 2, 
              3, 3,
                 4)
```

Also z2 get be done with for() loops

```
temp <- z1
res <- c()

for (i in 1:length(z1)){
    
    res <- c(res, temp)
    temp <- temp[-1]
    
}

res <- c(1, 2, 3, 4,
            2, 3, 4,
               3, 4,
                  4)
```

But is there any ways to transform z1 to z2 with one string built-in functions like rep()?

Comment: Maybe `unlist(sapply(1:length(z1),function(i)z1[i:length(z1)]))`

Comment: A slight variation: `unlist(sapply(seq_along(z1),function(i)z1[seq_along(z1)>=i]))`

Comment: I wanted to make sequence like z2 from z1 with any vector, so elements of z1 can be float numbers and not sorted

Comment: An option with `rep` would be `n <- length(z1);
 n1 <- seq_len(n)-1;
 c(na.omit(rep(z1, n) * rep(rep(c(NA, 1), 4), c(0, n) + c(rbind(n1, -n1)))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `sapply` + `unlist` + `tail` like below

```
> unlist(sapply(-seq_along(z1), tail, x = c(NA, z1)))
 [1] 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c(z1, unlist(lapply(1:length(z1), function(x) z1[-c(1:x)])))
[1] 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: updating post to account for an ordered solution

Populate a matrix by repeating every value the maximum number of times. Then take the lower triangle of the matrix. Note: using `length(z1)` in this case so that the values are note required to be integers, use `max(z1)` instead if that value would make sense.

```
z2 <- matrix(data = rep(z1, times = length(z1)), ncol = length(z1), byrow = FALSE)
z2
```

Resulting matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

Subset the matrix using `lower.tri` to extract the lower triangle and the diagonal

```
z2 <- z2[lower.tri(z2, diag = TRUE)]
print(z2)
```

Result

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 3 4 4
```

---

*Previous partial solution (for an unordered solution)*

Use `lapply` to iterate through the vector, with each iteration, repeat each element the desired number of times using `rep`, and then `unlist` the result to turn it into a vector

```
 z1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4) 
 z2 <- unlist(lapply(z1, function(x) rep(x, times = x)))
 print(z2)
```

Result

```
 [1] 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: I did miss that. I'll revise.

Answer (score 0):

Base R using eval parse:

```
z1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4) 
max_num <- max(z1)
unlist(lapply(paste(z1, max_num, sep = ":"), function(x){
      eval(parse(text=x))
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: But why? `eval(parse())` is an exceptionally bug-prone way to do most things.